# After updating to Ubuntu 23.10, some applications appear as a gear icon in the dock and have unthemed title bars

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, dock, titlebar

After upgrading from Ubuntu 23.04 to Ubuntu 23.10, some applications that I use (e.g., TeXworks and DiffPDF, both installed from the "universe" apt repository) show up in my Gnome dock as a gear icon, even though the correct icons show up when searching for these applications from the Gnome activities search bar.

Also, the title bar on both of these applications no longer follows the Ubuntu Gnome theme:

[image: screenshot]

Here is a screenshot showing the gear icons in the dock and the unthemed title bar on DiffPDF (foreground window) compared with the correctly themed title bar on Gnome Terminal (background window)

I would appreciate any thoughts on whether this is a bug, or if there is anything I can do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue here with applications like Transmission or Simplescan after a fresh installation as I remember.

It appears that I have this issue for non snap applications so I removed the apt package (i.e for transmission and simple-scan) and re-installed using snap store. Not very elegant, especially for whom doesn't want snap or for applications not available there, but it works.

Comment: Please don't post "I have the same problems" as "Answer"